# Filtering Listview not appearing on UI

Tags: java, android, listview, filter, adapter

I have an Activity (InputActivity) that contain an edittext with a listview. There are lots of examples out there on that. As the user types in the edit text, I want the listview to filter based on the what's typed, so I implemented a filter.

However, the change is not being reflected in the UI (I am using a list of hashmaps to populate the listview components...I am suspecting an issue could be there?). The perform filtering method is picking up the right options, but I am less certain of publishResults() and getFilter() working properly.

**InputActivity**
    package mjd.mdflip.areyoudrunk.activities;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import mjd.mdflip.areyoudrunk.R;
import mjd.mdflip.areyoudrunk.adapters.InputArrayAdapter;
import mjd.mdflip.areyoudrunk.data.DBmanager;

public class InputActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button;
    long returnPosition;
    ListView listview;
    String[] description;
    InputArrayAdapter adapter;
    EditText etUserInput;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        setContentView(R.layout.page_input_activity);

        returnPosition = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("position",0);
        Log.i("Position of list","Element in list: " + returnPosition);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        etUserInput =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        adapter = parameterDependentLogic(returnPosition);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                finishActivity(description[position],returnPosition);
            }

        });

        etUserInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                InputActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0.toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private InputArrayAdapter parameterDependentLogic(long returnPosition) {


        Integer position = (int) (long) returnPosition;
        Log.i("Position", "Return position:" + returnPosition);

        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String [] from = new String[] { "description", "value" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvDescription, R.id.tvInput};


        switch(position){

            //barName
            case 0:


                DBmanager db = new DBmanager(this);
                db.open();
                description = db.getBarNames();
                db.close();



                for (int i = 0; i < description.length; i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("description", description[i]);
                    fillMaps.add(map);
                }

                adapter = new InputArrayAdapter(this, fillMaps,
                        R.layout.component_text_input_list, from, to);

                break;
            case 1:

                DBmanager info = new DBmanager(this);
                info.open();
                description = info.loadAutoCompleteDrinks();
                info.close();


                for (int i = 0; i < description.length; i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("description", description[i]);
                    fillMaps.add(map);
                }

                adapter = new InputArrayAdapter(this, fillMaps,
                        R.layout.component_text_input_list, from, to);

                break;
            case 2:

                etUserInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

                description = new String[] { "Light Beer (4.2%)", "IPA (5.5%)" };

                for (int i = 0; i < description.length; i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("description", description[i]);
                    fillMaps.add(map);
                }

                adapter = new InputArrayAdapter(this, fillMaps,
                        R.layout.component_text_input_list, from, to);

                break;
            case 3:

                etUserInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

                break;
            case 4:

                etUserInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

                description = new String[] { "Draft Beer (16 oz)", "Bottle Beer (12 oz)", "Pitcher (64 oz)" };

                for (int i = 0; i < description.length; i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("description", description[i]);
                    fillMaps.add(map);
                }

                adapter = new InputArrayAdapter(this, fillMaps,
                        R.layout.component_text_input_list, from, to);

                break;


        }

    return adapter;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText etUserInput =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String userValue = etUserInput.getText().toString().trim();

        if(userValue.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter a value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            if (returnPosition == 4) {
                userValue = userValue + " oz";
            } else if (returnPosition == 3) {
                userValue = "$" + userValue;
            } else if (returnPosition == 2) {
                userValue = userValue + "%";
            }

            finishActivity(userValue, returnPosition);
        }
    }

    private void finishActivity(String value, long position){

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("value", value);
        returnIntent.putExtra("position", position);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        onBackPressed();


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }

}
```

**InputArrayAdapter**

```
package mjd.mdflip.areyoudrunk.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class InputArrayAdapter extends SimpleAdapter  implements Filterable {


    private List<? extends HashMap<String, ?>> drinkList;
    private Context context;
    private Filter drinkFilter;
    private List<? extends HashMap<String, ?>> origDrinkList;

    public InputArrayAdapter(Context context,
                             List<? extends HashMap<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from,
                             int[] to) {

        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.drinkList = data;
        this.context = context;
        this.origDrinkList = data;

    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        return row;

    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        if (drinkFilter == null) {
            drinkFilter = new DrinkFilter();
            Log.i("New filt","Def new");
        }

        return drinkFilter;
    }



private class DrinkFilter extends Filter {



    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        // We implement here the filter logic

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            // No filter implemented we return all the list
            results.values = origDrinkList;
            results.count = origDrinkList.size();

        }
        else {
            // We perform filtering operation

            List<HashMap<String, String>> nDrinkList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (HashMap<String, ?> map : origDrinkList) {

                for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    Object value = entry.getValue();
                    String drinkName = value.toString();
                    HashMap<String, String> tmp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    if (drinkName.toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        tmp.put("description", drinkName);
                        Log.i("Drink Found", drinkName);
                        nDrinkList.add(tmp);
                    }
                }
            }

            results.values = nDrinkList;
            results.count = nDrinkList.size();

        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  Filter.FilterResults results) {

        // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
        if (results.count == 0)
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        else {
            drinkList = (List<HashMap<String, String>>) results.values;
            Log.i("New options","Num of drunks:" + drinkList.size() );
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}



    }
```

Comment: Did you confirm that notifyDataSetChanged() does get called?

Comment: I know that the line above it is getting called, in the very least (which is in the same if block).

Comment: When you first populate the ListView you pass in the list of items you want. After filtering do you update the adapter with the new list?

Comment: My understanding is I am updating drinkList with the new list, which should be returned with InputActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0.toString());... but now I'm starting to second guess myself and think there is not enough in getView

Comment: I don't see you doing a setAdapter() any place other than onCreate(). Anytime you update the list you should do setAdapter() before calling the notify function.